# Animating a height value for text input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

So i am using  react-native-autogrow-textinput in order to have an editable document viewable in my application. I am currently trying to work around the keyboard in order to adjust the height of textinput box, so that all text is visible. I have found the following code to do so

```
componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}

keyboardDidShow(e){
    let newSize = Dimensions.get('window').height- e.endCoordinates.height - 150;
    console.log(e.endCoordinates);
    this.setState({docViewHeight: newSize});
}

keyboardDidHide(e){
    let newSize = Dimensions.get('window').height - 170;
    this.setState({docViewHeight: newSize})
}
```

However, the result i am getting is: When the keyboard is animating off screen, the height of the textinput remains the same, `let newSize = Dimensions.get('window').height- e.endCoordinates.height - 150`, untill the keyboard has finished sliding off screen.

The height then adjusts to fill the whole screen again, except it sort of 'pops' into the new height. How do i get the value of this height to gradually grow, so it looks like it is simply extending to fit the whole screen? Ill post my Autogrow TextInput code below also. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<AutoGrowingTextInput
                    ref="editText"
                    editable = {this.state.editting}
                    style = {{fontSize: fontProperties.fontSize+3, marginLeft: 18, marginRight: 18, marginTop: 15}}
/*animate this*/    minHeight = {this.state.docViewHeight}
                    animation = {{animated: true, duration: 300}}
                    //has some other confidential props here for onChange etc
</AutoGrowingTextInput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, after digging through some library files.

The solution is to use a `keyboardWillHide` event listener instead of `keyboardDidHide`.

This will fire before the keyboard begins its outro animation. Ive put the code below.

```
componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    this.keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
}

keyboardWillHide(e){
    let newSize = Dimensions.get('window').height - 170;
    this.setState({docViewHeight: newSize})
}
```